# Load Databound Images and Thumbs onClick using Databinding

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Through some research I found out how to display full images by clicking on the thumbnail which are stored in separate folders. The code works fine if you are only pointing to one folder but i have multiple folders of images that i need opened because there are a large number of images stored. What i have done is created an ASP:TreeView for this. Previously when i coded this a different way, I was able to just type enter:

```
string textVal = TreeView2.SelectedValue;             
(Server.MapPath("~/images/Thumbs/" + textVal));
```

now that doesn't seem to be working for me. I think for the JQuery i can just use .replace but for the C# I've tried a few things but none of them seem to be working.
(p.s. if you are going to criticize please save your time and just don't. Most of us come here for help and to learn, not to be put down and discouraged, thanks :])

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string textVal = TreeView2.SelectedValue;
        Repeater1.Visible = true;

        List<MyImages> myImages = new List<MyImages>();
        DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/images/Thumbs/Fall/2006/"));
        foreach (var file in DI.GetFiles())
        {
            myImages.Add(new MyImages { FileName = file.Name });
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = myImages;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

}

public class MyImages
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ImageGallery img').click(function () {
            var fullImg = '/images/Fall/2006/' + $(this).attr('alt');
            $('#fullImg').attr('src', fullImg);
        });
    });

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <img src='/images/Thumbs/Fall/2006/<%#Eval("FileName") %>' alt='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' width="100px" style="cursor: pointer" /
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think many people will view this thread but i will show how I figured it out after messing around with it for quite some time.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string textVal = TreeView2.SelectedValue;

        Repeater1.Visible = true;

        List<MyImages> myImages = new List<MyImages>();
        DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/images/Thumbs/" + textVal));           

        foreach (var file in DI.GetFiles())
        {
            myImages.Add(new MyImages { FileName = textVal + "/" + file.Name });
        }

        Repeater1.DataSource = myImages;
        Repeater1.DataBind();        
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ImageGallery img').click(function () {
            var fullImage= $(this).attr('alt');
            //var fullImage= $(this).attr('alt');
            $('#fullImage').attr('src', fullImage);
        });
    });

                                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>                                           
                                        <img src='images/thumbs/<%#Eval("FileName") %>' alt='images/<%#Eval("FileName") %>'/>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```